# Arc length of this function

Tags: calculus, integration

It is given that $x^2=(2y)^2$, he asks to give the arc length of this function,  $1\leq x \leq 2\sqrt2$. Answer is $1/27 (19^{3/2} - 10^{3/2})$.

Comment: Maybe you "need" to see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/129028).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how $1/27 (19^{3/2} - 10^{3/2}) \approx 1.8962\\$ is the right answer. That is not the answer I get.

Using the Arc length formula:

$$L = \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1 + \left[{dy \over dx}\right]^2} \,dx $$

The derivative:

$$y = {x\over2} \to{dy \over dx} = {1 \over 2}$$

The integral:

$$\begin{align}
L & = \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1 + \left[{1\over2}\right]^2} \,dx \\
& = \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1 + {1\over4}} \,dx \\
& = \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{{4\over4} + {1\over4}} \,dx \\
& = \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{{5\over4}} \,dx \\
& = {1\over2} \int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{5} \,dx \\
& = \left[{\sqrt{5}\,x\over2} \right]_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}}\\
& = {2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5} - \sqrt{5}\over2} \\
& = {\sqrt{5}(2\sqrt{2}\ - 1)\over 2}\\
& \approx 2.0442\\
\end{align}$$

$$ 2.0442 \neq 1.8962$$

Comment: I understand that, however I can't reach that answer. Should I isolate 'y'? Even so, I'm getting different answers, I would apreciate if someone answer that.

Comment: @JoãoPedro I've updated my answer